# How does one become a Mohel?

Tags: brit-milah, adult-learning

I want to be a Mohel.

I learned the Tur - Shulchan Aruch (YD 260-266).

Now what?

What should be my next step?

P.S. I live in Brooklyn.

Comment: Find a mohel who is willing to teach you. He'll probably advise you were to buy the equipment, and teach you whatever isn't in the book. Good luck!

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49211/5323

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the best option is to learn from a mohel or get good advice from a good mohel. The best and most friendliest Mohel I know is Rav Paysach Krohn, [this web site](http://brisquest.com/) has his number and email. I know that he's busy doing britot and lecturing, but, at worst, if he can't train you, I'm quite certain he will advise and, if appropriate, recommend you to the right person. (He may also try to sell you one of his many books. At least you may get them autographed :-)

Another possibility is to contact his son in law, Rav Ephra'im Perlstein, who is also a mohel, info [here](http://medl.io/ephraim-perlstein).

If you do, eventually become a mohel, I may ask you for some "tips" :-( :-(

Comment: Somehow, I don't think Rabbi Paysach Krohn is available to give lessons. He  keeps an *extremely* packed schedule.

Answer (score 8):

My brother in law who became a Mohel apprenticed for a while with a Mohel who was doing it for many years. When the Mohel was confident in his abilities he gave him the go ahead to do it on his own.

I have also heard that many times a new Mohel after apprenticing begins by doing a Bris on his own child.

I am pretty certain that most Mohelim begin this way.

Comment: I strongly recommend getting some cow penises from a slaughterhouse and practicing on them before you maim your own son.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Interesting; I'd never heard of someone doing that (practicing on cows). Anecdotally, my father (a surgeon) did mine....but he had done hundreds before that, in the hospital. And he had a professional mohel watching.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Is that a joke? A cow foreskin isn't the same as a human one.

Comment: Yes, the bull's penis is different from the human's in many respects, but in some respects it is similar enough to provide good practice for one learning how to be  a mohel.

Comment: @ClintEastwood How do you know that?

Comment: Because it is a penis with skin and one can practice cutting it quickly without damaging it and he the feel of using the instruments. Lots of surgical procedures are trained for with animals.