# Are there any safrut teachers in Boston?

Tags: adult-learning, safrus

I have, as I've expressed in previous questions, a strong interest in safrut. As such, I would love to learn the relevant halachot and beautify my writing, which although it would likely be kosher (were I educated in the halachot) is not what I'd expect of a sofer.

Is there anyone in the Boston area who teaches hilchot safrut and sta"m?

Comment: For the halachos, I've heard that most use קסת הסופר.....see if your local *seforim* store has a copy. [HB link](http://hebrewbooks.org/7521)

Comment: I edited the title of your question to better portray your question.....I clicked on the question, thinking that I would answer "learn קסת הסופר, and find a *sofer* to show you how to make things look pretty" ....if you don't agree, you could always [edit] some more yourself. הצלחה!

Comment: @Shokhet, is ספר קסת הסופר available in English?

Comment: Not that I know of. Ask at your local seforim store ;-)

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48825/5323

Comment: ask rabbi moskowitz near there http://www.chaiodom.com/rabbi.html I know him well.

Comment: @Shokhet, http://www.hasoferet.com/halakha-for-scribes/keset-ha-sofer/ I've not learned this copy, but it's good to have on the forum.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some Googling for this question, I found [this listing](http://www.jewishboston.com/resources/21332-rabbi-shimon-miara-mohel) on [jewishboston.com](http://www.jewishboston.com/):

> Rabbi Shimon Miara
>   (617) 783-2249
>   http://newenglandmohel.com
>
> Expert mohel in the Greater Boston area and out of state. Safrut
>   classes for parents and children in day schools, and afternoon
>   activities around Boston and New England.

Like I [said in the comments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/49211/are-there-any-safrut-teachers-in-boston/50922#comment131081_49211), I would recommend learning קסת הסופר ([HebrewBooks](http://hebrewbooks.org/7521)) first, because he'll probably tell you to learn it, anyway (several of my friends are learning ספרות, and all of them have been told to use this sefer).

Good luck!

Comment: FWIW, I emailed R' Miara several months ago to ask about this. He as not replied as of the time of this writing.

Comment: I dunno... I can't claim to know him personally, but that's what I got from Google... Has any of your other research returned anything?

Comment: I've met him. I've heard that he makes the family responsible for the orlot, unlike most other local mohelim, who deal with the disposal.

Comment: My other research has been equally fruitless. The International Stam Forum has the name of a sofer in the area, but I don't know how to contact him.

Comment: :/ ...best of luck! I hope you find someone soon

Comment: Just curious; have you been learning the קסת הסופר?

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually going to try and call the Va'ad Mishmereth Stam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25160/discussion-between-noach-mi-frankfurt-and-shokhet).

Comment: I ran into R' Miara a few weeks ago at a friend's son's bris. I asked him if he taught and he says that he no longer does so.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt That's too bad...did you ever find a different teacher? Was R' Miara able to recommend a teacher?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt You might be out of luck in Boston proper. But, you might also try contacting [Rabbi Naftoly Bier](http://www.bostonkollel.com/index.php/rabbi-naftoly-bier), Rosh Kollel of the Boston Kollel. If anyone can point you in the right direction, he can. You might also try garnering the advice of Rabbi Aharon Hamaoui of [The Sephardic Community of Greater Boston](http://godaven.com/detail.asp?Id=4329).