# Online Safrut Courses

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, chinuch-education, safrus

In [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/49211/are-there-any-safrut-teachers-in-boston), I asked about any safrut teachers in my area. As of present, I have not heard back from the sofer provided in the link.

However, I was wondering, as a corollary, considering the online education industry of the modern day, whether there were any online courses dealing in hilchot safrut and k'tav. I would be looking for an experienced sofer whose course is taught with Orthodox, particularly more modern, students in mind.

Answer (score 7):

I just saw your question and wanted to let you know there is an online safrut course starting on November 15th. All the information can be found here:
http://mastery.webyeshiva.org/safrut-certification/

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Amihai, and thanks for linking us to this course.